# How to get a specific value from JavaScript to C# coding?

Tags: javascript, html

After creating everything by the JavaScript dynamically I want to move a single specific value into my C# code; I don't want everything, I have written in the code that which variable I want to be moved into my C# code:

```
<script>      
    var test="i want this variable into my c#";
    var only for javascript="i don't want this to be travel when i click on submit button";

    var s = document.createElement("input"); //input element, Submit button
    s.setAttribute('type', "submit");
    s.setAttribute('value', "submit");
</script>
```

Comment: To get better answers, please review and revise your question (particularly, the code): http://sscce.org/

Comment: sorry i know the code was lil bit confusing i have wrote the code again i think it will give u a idea that what i want to know .?

Answer (score 0):

To get a client variable "into c#", you need to make it part of a request to the server where c# is running. This can be as simple as appending it to a URL, or you may create a new field, or you may populate an existing field and send it.

```
// a variable
var test = "a value to be sent to the server";

// put the value into a hidden field
document.getElementById("hdnValue").value = test;

// submit the form containing the hidden field
document.getElementById("form1").submit();
```

Since we are talking about c#, I assume the server is ASP.Net, either web forms or MVC. For MVC, ensure that there is a controller method that takes a corresponding parameter. For web forms, you may include `<input type="hidden" runat="server" clientidmode="static" id="hdnValue" />`. The page will then have access to this value in the code behind.

> i want to travel a single specific value into my c# code ... i don't
>   want everything

An alternate (and possibly more elegant) way of sending a single value to the server is to POST the value asynchronously using AJAX. I would suggest using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to make this easier, but it can also be done in plain JavaScript.

Here's a jQuery example of an AJAX post:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://yourserverurl/",
    type: "POST",
    data: { test: "a value to be sent to the server" },
    success: function(data){
        // an optional javascript function to call when the operation completes successfully
    }
});
```